# node.js cluster module + unix sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix, cluster-computing

I'm trying to use node's built in cluster module and, when using ports, everything works just fine. However, when attempting to use unix sockets instead thing's don't work out so well:

error: Error: ENOENT, unlink '/tmp/socket.sock'

It never creates this file ... when not using a unix socket, however, everything work just fine.

For reference, my code looks something like this:
https://github.com/jmonster/node-clustrap

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved in the latest node-clustrap -- the problem was unlinking the socket in each child process instead of only doing it once in the master. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: What did you do to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was that I had been unlinking the socket before creation unconditionally.

The master was successfully creating the socket, and then each worker was deleting it!

I moved the `unlink` call into the section of code that only applied to master to fix it.